# Pandas split-apply-combine, why combining with pd.concat([df]) works when sorting?

Tags: python, pandas, merge, pandas-groupby, pandas-apply

I do a split-apply-merge type of workflow with pandas. The 'apply' part returns a `DataFrame`. When the DataFrame I run `gropupby` on is firstly sorted, simply returning a `DataFrame` from `apply` raises `ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis`. Instead, I have found it to work properly when I return `pd.concat([df])` (instead of just `return df`). If I don't sort the `DataFrame`, both ways of merging results work correctly. I expect sorting must be doing something to the index yet I don't understand what. Can someone please explain?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


def fill_out_ids(df, filling_function, sort=False, sort_col='sort_col',
                 group_by='group_col', to_fill=['id1', 'id2']):

    df = df.copy()
    df.set_index(group_by, inplace=True)
    if sort:
        df.sort_values(by=sort_col, inplace=True)
    g = df.groupby(df.index, sort=False, group_keys=False)
    df = g.apply(filling_function, to_fill)
    df.reset_index(inplace=True)
    return df


def _fill_ids_concat(df, to_fill):
    df[to_fill] = df[to_fill].fillna(method='ffill')
    df[to_fill] = df[to_fill].fillna(method='bfill')
    return pd.concat([df])


def _fill_ids_plain(df, to_fill):
    df[to_fill] = df[to_fill].fillna(method='ffill')
    df[to_fill] = df[to_fill].fillna(method='bfill')
    return df


def test_fill_out_ids():
    input_df = pd.DataFrame(
        [
            ['a',       None,       1.0,    1],
            ['a',       None,       1.0,    3],
            ['a',       'name1',    np.nan, 2],

            ['b',       None,       2.0,    3],
            ['b',       'name1',    np.nan, 2],
            ['b',       'name2',    np.nan, 1],
        ],
        columns=['group_col', 'id1', 'id2', 'sort_col']
    )

    # this works
    fill_out_ids(input_df, _fill_ids_plain, sort=False)

    # this raises: ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis
    fill_out_ids(input_df, _fill_ids_plain, sort=True)

    # this works
    fill_out_ids(input_df, _fill_ids_concat, sort=True)

    # this works
    fill_out_ids(input_df, _fill_ids_concat, sort=False)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    test_fill_out_ids()
```

Comment: Could you include a [mcve] for just the operation that is puzzling you?

Comment: wwii thanks for your feedback. I edited the question and also doing that, I have tracked down the reason for my confusion a little bit. Sorting the DataFrame seems to be important here.

Comment: .. If you get the groups individually and call the plain version, they work ... `b = g.get_group('b'); _fill_ids_plain(b, to_fill)` .. but it doesn't like applying it to the groupby object

Comment: Totally by accident.

Comment: Do you just want to know why this happens or are you looking for other solutions that work when the DataFrame is sorted.?

Comment: I want to understand why it works with `pd.concat()` and what the `sort_values` does to the index. Looking at the DataFrame in the debugger I don't see any obvious explanations.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34018827/2823755

Comment: that's already something :)